# There is no option to set ARC flag in xamarin ios build configurations

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Apple has raised warning as Automatic Reference Counting is not enabled for my one application. In the previous version of visual studio there was one checkbox for enabling ARC but now we don't have any checkbox. I tried to set flag as **-gcc_flags "-fobjc-arc"**, but i don't think it is the proper solution. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: `As of Xamarin 9.2.1 the new ref counting system is enabled to all applications by default.` Which version of Xamarin.iOS are you using?

Comment: I am using xamarin.ios 13.10.0.17. Why apple has raised warning then that ARC is not enabled. Also how can i check in my application if ARC flag is enabled?

Comment: @abmuiz Hi , I think if not adding that flag , the application will not enable ARC as default .

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT, Do you mean **-gcc_flags "-fobjc-arc"** flag? If  i add this flag then how can i check if my ipa is ARC enabled or not. Is there any way to check that? or do you know another way to enable it?

Comment: @abmuiz If added `-gcc_flags "-fobjc-arc"` , the project will always show that in **additional mtouch arguments** .If in an existing application , you can check `.csproj` file to ensure whether contain that . I have no idea about other ways to enable that . Xamarin has its new ref counting system from Xamarin 9.2.1 .I think if not necessary ,not need to enable ARC .